# Mac OS X fastboot is just waiting (HTC M8 T-Mobile)

Tags: fastboot, macos, htc-one-m8

I'm trying to run `fastboot oem get_identifier_token` on Mac OS X Yosemite but I get stuck on "< waiting for device >":

```
➜  platform-tools  ./adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
FA495WM04764    device

➜  platform-tools  sudo ./fastboot oem get_identifier_token
< waiting for device >
```

- I have enabled USB debugging
- I have tried both sudo and no sudo on fastboot
- I have tried restarting, changing USB ports (although they are just two on my Mac Book Pro Mid-2012).
- The SDK is the latest one, downloaded today from `http://developer.android.com/` together with `Android Studio`
- I also tried downloading just `fastboot-mac` from HTC dev site, same happens there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the device connected is booted into fastboot mode? To me that looks like it's booted "normally".

Comment: As Izzy alludes to, fastboot is a different completely separate boot mode. If `adb` is recognizing your device then fastboot won't be able to communicate with it, because it is not running on the device's side. Try `adb reboot bootloader` before issuing the fastboot commands.

Comment: Guys, that was the issue I realised it a bit after I posted the question. If someone adds the answer, I will accept it for other lost souls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have commented you need to reboot your device in bootloader (fastboot) mode.

Easiest way, is to use the command

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

Your device will reboot and will end up in the fastboot mode. Now you can use the `fastboot` utility.